# How can I access to a specific field on a document with meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I was able to get the `User` document with this code

```js
Users.findOne(userId)
```

also `Users` looks like this.

```js
{
  "_id" : "123sdasdasd",
  "createdAt" : ISODate("2022-06-15T20:36:01.549+0000"),
  "archived" : false,
  "roles" : {
      "internal" : [
          "admin",
          "maneger"
      ],
      "client" : [
          "admin",
          "maneger",
          "normal-user",
      ],
      "other" : [
          "admin",
          "maneger",
          "normal-user",
          "manage"
      ],
  },
  "username" : "sample@gmail.com"
}
```

My goal here is to make sure if this user has a `roles` column with `client`.

I believe this is on the server side but part of my code looks like this.

```js
Roles.removeUsers = (userId, groupName) => {

  console.log(Users.findOne(userId)); // got document successfully 
  console.log(Users.findOne(userId).roles[groupName]); // got undefined

  if (Users.findOne(userId).roles[groupName].length < 1) {
    sampledataUpdate.$pull.userIds = userId;
  }
};
```

The `groupName` could be `internal`, `client`, `other` or other strings.

Currently, I'm getting `groupName` as `client`.

How can I make sure if this user has `client` in `roles` column?

also another little question is if you look at the data structure above,

can I say `roles` as `column`?

`_id`, `createdAt`, `archived` are `column`?

and inside of column(roles for this case),
what is the right word to describe `internal`, `client` or `other`?
Would that be `key`?

Thank you!

Comment: Use this package: https://github.com/Meteor-Community-Packages/meteor-roles

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with this way.

```
if (Users.find({ _id: userId, [`roles.${groupName}`]: { $exists: true }}).count()) {
  // .......
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is right. To make the search faster, you can add also indexes to "internal", "client" and "other" fields of roles field. I don't know, If I understand correctly to your sub-question about the columns. You can say "roles as field" of "Users collection document".